# sort two string arrays respectively in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, string, sorting, date

I am looking for a simple way to sort 2 arrays, one contains dates and the other contains time for each specipic date (the date in the first place of ar1 match the time in the first place of ar2)

```
var ar1 = ["2014-02-13", "2016-03-01", "2015-03-17", "2014-04-02", "2014-04-18"]
var ar2 = ["08:11:57", "08:11:43", "08:11:34", "08:11:18", "08:11:01"]
ar1.sort()
print(ar1)
```

> > output : ["2014-02-13", "2014-04-02", "2014-04-18", "2015-03-17", "2016-03-01"]

I need ar2 to change respectively to ar1

```
ar2 needs to be : ["08:11:57", "08:11:18", "08:11:01", "08:11:34", "08:11:43"]
```

Comment: You need to use a struct to store the both the values in a single array. Then sort the array based on the required string variable.

Comment: Please share the code you tried to sort first array i.e, `ar1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **`zip(_:_:)`** both the arrays `ar1` and `ar2` and call **`sorted(_:)`** on the resulting array based on `ar1`, i.e.

```
let result = zip(ar1, ar2).sorted { $0.0 < $1.0 }

let sortedAr1 = result.map({ $0.0 }) //["2014-02-13", "2014-04-02", "2014-04-18", "2015-03-17", "2016-03-01"]

let sortedAr2 = result.map({ $0.1 }) //["08:11:57", "08:11:18", "08:11:01", "08:11:34", "08:11:43"]
```

Instead of using `zip`, you can create an `array` of `struct/class` instances as well wherein each instance store corresponding elements from  `ar1` and `ar2`. Then `sort` that `array` based on the `ar1` values.

This is better approach if you're okay with the changing the structure from 2 `String` `arrays` to a single `struct` `array`.

Comment: Another option, considering the type of data, is to concatenate each pair of elements into a date/time string or even parse them into a `Date` object

Answer (score 0):

Make a struct or a class to store the data. Then create an array of that class/struct and sort it by date.

```swift
struct MyDates {
   var date: String
   var time: String
}

let date1 = MyDates(date: "2014-02-13", time: "08:11:57")
let date2 = MyDates(date: "2016-03-01", time: "08:11:43")

var arrayDate = [date2, date1]
arrayDate.sort { $0.date < $1.date }
```